# Is there a problem with github and Python 3.8? Why can't I run this code?

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to run this code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist
!./python-mnist/get_data.sh
!pip3 install emnist
from emnist import extract_training_samples
```

But the following error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/silteliz/Desktop/Solo Learn Python/NN 1.py", line 1
    !git clone https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have Python 3.8. Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: You seem to have a "!" before each command, it should be:
git clone https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist

Comment: I already tried to run it without the "!", but the same error message appears: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/silteliz/Desktop/Solo Learn Python/NN 1.py", line 1
    git clone https://github.com/sorki/python-mnist
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: From where did you get this list of commands?

Comment: Do you need to have this in your python file? Unless i am missing something, those commands should be ran on the terminal, and not with python.

Comment: @usr2564301 From an online course/lab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NyYH1EPpaJlMBLK0fcKYz4icaD1SNSLK#scrollTo=bGP5woydMEMa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `!` if you're using `ipython`, for instance in Jupyter Notebook or the console of PyCharm **if** you enabled `ipython` as the default console interface. If this is not the case, drop the `!` and write the rest of your code in `cmd`.

Comment: Thanks! I was using Thonny before, do you think that was the problem? I ran the following code form Jupyter Notebook and it did work: `!pip install emnist
from emnist import extract_training_samples`.

Comment: Thonny uses the Python shell, not ipython. So yes that was the problem